# integral of $\sec^3x\tan x$

Tags: calculus

I keep coming up with $1/\tan^2x + C$, and I know the correct answer is $(1/3)\sec^3x + C$

$u=sec^3x$

$du=sec^3x*tan^3x$

$dx=1/sec^3xtan^3x$

$u*tanx *1/sec^3xtan^3x + C$

$1/tan^2x + C$

I know I am going wrong somewhere, I just need to know where

Comment: Your $\mathrm{d}u$ is wrong.

Comment: ...and it lacks the $dx$ that helps you make the correct substitution.

Comment: It's one of the reasons for it being wrong :p

Answer (score 2):

Set $u = \sec(x)$. Recall that $du = \sec(x) \tan(x) dx$ and see the magic.

If you set $u = \sec^3(x)$, we then have $du = 3 \sec^2(x) \sec(x )\tan(x) dx = 3 \sec^3(x) \tan(x) dx$.

Comment: I set u=secx, then du=secx*tanx*dx, and dx= 1/secxtanx. This gave me u*2secx*secxtanx*sec^2x+C. Simplifying with u gave me 2sec^3x+C. I am getting closer but still going wrong somewhere.

Comment: I'm going to try it a different way: sec^3x*tan^3x*dx = (secx)^2*secx*tanx*dx           u=secx, du=secx*tanx       (secx)^2*secx*tanx = u^2*du    (1/n+1)*u^(n+1) = (1/2+1)*u^(2+1) = (1/3)u^3  =  (1/3)(secx)^3

Answer (score 0):

Directly, using that

$$n\neq-1\implies\int f'(x)\,f(x)^ndx=\frac{f(x)^{n+1}}{n+1}+C :$$

$$\int\sec^3x\tan x\;dx=-\int\overbrace{(-\sin x)}^{=(\cos x)'}\cos^{-4}x\;dx=-\frac{\cos^{-3}x}{-3}+C=\frac13\sec^3x+C$$